Notation for group representations
I wrote a sentence in my draft version of paper " A representation of a group $G$ is defined as a pair $(V, \rho)$, where $V$ represents a vector space and $\rho: G \to \text{Aut}(V)$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to the automorphism group of $V$. While $\rho$ is sometimes defined from $G$ to $\text{GL}(V)$, opting for $\text{Aut}(V)$ ensures well-definedness when $V$ is the vector space of $S^N$ of $N \times N$ symmetric matrices."
Is writing such a sentence appropriate? Moreover, in my paper, $V$ can be $\mathbb{R}^N$, $\mathbb{C}^N$, and $S^N$. Now, which notation is better for the image of $\rho$? $\text{Aut}(V)$ or $\text{GL}(V)$?
I also have another notational question. I want to refer as orthogonal representation by $\rho:G \to O(N)$, where $O(N)$ denotes the orthogonal group of dimension $N$. Is this fine? I am asking this because I have seen $\rho:G \to U(N)$ denotes the unitary representations, but I have not seen the similar one over reals.

A minor point: You needn’t say that $V$ “represents” a vector space. It is a vector space.

Good point, thank you.


A representation of a group $G$ is defined as a pair $(V, \rho)$, where $V$ represents a vector space and $\rho: G \to \text{Aut}(V)$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to the automorphism group of $V$.

This is fine, although as Paul says in the comments you can just say "$V$ is a vector space."

While $\rho$ is sometimes defined from $G$ to $\text{GL}(V)$, opting for $\text{Aut}(V)$ ensures well-definedness when $V$ is the vector space of $S^N$ of $N \times N$ symmetric matrices.

This is awkward and unclear. $GL(V)$ and $\text{Aut}(V)$ mean the same thing so it doesn't matter all that much which one you pick. $S^N$ is very unusual notation for the $N \times N$ symmetric matrices (typically in this context it would refer to the symmetric power) and you haven't explained why this case matters to you.

Now, which notation is better for the image of $\rho$? $\text{Aut}(V)$ or $\text{GL}(V)$?

You mean the codomain? Either is fine, although personally I think $GL(V)$ is slightly clearer and more appropriate. $\text{Aut}(V)$ is ambiguous because e.g. at some point you might want to refer to the automorphism group of $V$ as a representation.

I want to refer as orthogonal representation by $\rho:G \to O(N)$, where $O(N)$ denotes the orthogonal group of dimension $N$. Is this fine?

This is fine and you can see people use this terminology if you google it.

I have $\sigma: G \to \text{Aut}(\mathcal{S}^N )$, where $\sigma$ is induced by $\rho: G \to O(N)$ via $\sigma_gX=\rho_g^TX\rho_g$; I work with invariant optimization problems whose underlying vector space is the space of real symmetric matrices. Here, $\mathcal{S}^N$ is a standard notation.  Even the set of positive semidefinite matrices are shown by $\mathcal{S}^N_+$. I have found $\text{GL}(\mathcal{S}^N)$ awkward, whereas $\mathcal{S}^N$  can be identified as real vector space of dimension $\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$. Now, what do you suggest? Have you seen $\text{GL}(\mathcal{S}^N)$?

I have never seen $S^N$ in the first place. This is a stylistic decision, I don't have any hard and fast rules to offer you. I stand by my claim that $GL$ is a bit less ambiguous but it's up to you.
